# How should I interpret a negative partial derivative?

Tags: partial-derivative

I calculated the partial derivatives for $f(x,y)=x*y$ and I got that for x it's $y$ and for y it's $x$, pretty simple. Then, at point $(2; -3)$ I get that the partial derivative with respect to x is -3 and with respect to y it's 2. How can I interpret this?

Can I say that for each unit x increases, z decreases 3? And that for each unit y increases, z increases 2? Is that the right interpretation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Think of $z=f(x,y)$ as a topographical map.

[image]

Pretend you're standing at the point $(2,-3)$ (the black dot).  If you start walking East, you'll be going down a slope that is approximately $3$ feet down for every $1$ foot you walk Eastward.  If instead you started walking North, you'd be going *up* approximately $2$ feet up for every $1$ foot you walk North.

But then you might wonder what the slope is if you move in some other direction.  For that you'd use the *directional derivative*.  I'll spare you the derivation but it turns out the slope as you head in the direction of $\vec v = a\hat e_i + b\hat e_2$$^\dagger$ is approximately $\frac{-3a+2b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2}}$.

---

<sup>$\dagger$: $\hat e_1$ means walking $1$ foot East and likewise $\hat e_2$ is walking $1$ foot North.  So if, for instance you wanted to go $60^\circ$ East of South, using a little trigonometry you'd find that that would be going in the direction of $\vec v = \sqrt{3}\hat e_1 + \hat e_2$.</sup>

Comment: Thanks, great explanation! However, I'm a bit confused as to what the vector (a,b) is.

Comment: I get it now. Thanks again!

Comment: That would be nice. Thank you :)